# How to change which account Forge reference app looks at?

Tags: data-visualization, autodesk-forge, forge

I've been working with the forge reference app for a while now using a trial account, which has now expired, but my colleague wants to try running the app and uploading a new model to it.

I've switched over all the variables in the .env document to match their forge app (client Id, Secret etc) but when they go to upload a new model they get the following errors:

When uploading from my pc, despite having the .env file specify information for an app on their account:

```
{
  statusCode: 403,
  statusMessage: 'Forbidden',
  statusBody: {
    developerMessage: 'You are not allowed to use this API because your Forge trial is expired.',
    moreInfo: 'https://forgeautodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/develpoers_guide/error_handling/',
    errorCode: 'ERR-004'
  }
}
```

When uploading from their own pc using a copy of the project I sent over to them they get an error saying they don't have write access.

both these errors feel like they're caused from having the application associated to my account in some way, is there a way to change that and get it to use the credits from my colleagues account when uploading new models?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following in the `.env` file and then RESTART the app

```
FORGE_CLIENT_ID="NEW_CLIENT_ID"
FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET="NEW_CLIENT_SECRET"
FORGE_DOC_URN="urn:NEW_URN_TRANSLATED_WITH_NEW_FORGE_CLIENT_ID_and_SECRET"
```